# How to access a child object using OData, WebAPI and a DTO?

Tags: json, c#-4.0, odata, asp.net-web-api2

From a WebAPI controller, I am returning a list of `ProjectEditorDTO` objects from an OData request `/odata/ProjectEditor?$format=json&$inlinecount=allpages&$top=10`:

```
    [Queryable]
    public virtual IHttpActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<Website> odataQueryOptions)
    {
        var userId = UserContext.Identity.UserId;
        try
        {
            var results = odataQueryOptions.ApplyTo(_uow.Repository<Website>()
                .Query()
                .Get()
                .Where(u => u.UserId == userId)
                .OrderBy(o => o.WebsiteName)).Cast<Website>()
                .Select(s => new ProjectEditorDTO()
                {
                    // projection
                    WebsiteId = s.WebsiteId,
                    WebsiteGUID = s.WebsiteGUID,
                    WebsiteName = s.WebsiteName,
                    WebsiteNotes = s.WebsiteNotes,
                    DefaultContentTypeId = s.ContentType.ContentTypeId,
                    DefaultContentType = new ContentTypeDTO
                    {
                        ContentTypeId = s.ContentType.ContentTypeId,
                        Description = s.ContentType.Description
                    }
                });

            var r = results.ToList();
            . . .
```

JSON Output:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:1981/odata/$metadata#ProjectEditor","odata.count":"2","value":[
    {
      "WebsiteId":6,"WebsiteName":"Jobs","WebsiteGUID":"5252fa54-5cbc-4b7e-aa74-4fc2c5c90a6a","WebsiteNotes":"notes","DefaultContentTypeId":67
    },{
      "WebsiteId":7,"WebsiteName":"news","WebsiteGUID":"f0717700-5900-44f7-84a4-9dde9a451285","WebsiteNotes":"notes","DefaultContentTypeId":65
    }
  ]
}
```

In the projection, I define `DefaultContentType` but it does not appear in the JSON data returned to the client, even though it is visible at the `.ToList()` point.

I'm not trying to define a navigation property, so I should not (and can't) `$expand` it.

I could simply define a `DefaultContentTypeId` and `DefaultContentTypeDescription` in the projection, and would solve the problem.  However, I would like to know hot to get the `DefaultContentType` object to appear in the serialized JSON object.

**-- Update --**

ProjectEditorDTO:

```
public class ProjectEditorDTO
{
    [ForeignKey("DefaultContentTypeId")]
    public int WebsiteId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 3)]
    [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
    public string WebsiteName { get; set; }

    public string WebsiteGUID { get; set; }
    //public string WebsitePW { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteNotes { get; set; }

    public int DefaultContentTypeId { get; set; }
    public string DefaultContentTypeDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ContentTypeDTO DefaultContentType { get; set; }
}
```

ContentTypeDTO:

```
public class ContentTypeDTO
{
    public int ContentTypeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, MinimumLength=3)]
    [Display(Name="Content Type")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is ProjectEditorDTO an entity or a complex type? Can you provide your metadata?

Comment: @Schandlich - I added the classes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the CLR type ContentTypeDTO is an entity type in your metadata, which can be got by requesting

```
http://localhost:1981/odata/$metadata
```

Just change it to a Complex Type. Change

```
odataConventionModelBuilder.Entity<ContentTypeDTO>()
```

to

```
odataConventionModelBuilder.ComplexType<ContentTypeDTO>();
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  That worked, however I had the following route previously-defined: `modelBuilder.EntitySet<ContentTypeDTO>("ContentType");`, accessible through ~/odata/ContentType.  I can't define a type as both an `EntitySet` and `ComplexType`.  How can I get around this?

Comment: If ContentTypeDTO is an entity type then the DefaultContentType is a navigation property, so $expand has to be used.