# Returning related entities from functions in OData Web Api

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I've created an OData v4 endpoint using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 with 2 entities:

[image]

And i made function in my controller, that returns entity with related entity by using Include in LINQ:

```
[HttpGet]  
  [ODataRoute("SalaryNaryadWork/TechOrder.Functions.GetNaryadSalaryWork(pNaryadID={pNaryadID})")]
public IHttpActionResult GetNaryadSalaryWork(int pNaryadID)
{
var tmp =_ctx.SALARY_NARYAD_WORK.Include(s => s.SALARY_WORK_LIST).Where(sw => sw.NARYAD_ID == pNaryadID).ToList();
return Ok(tmp);
}
```

Function configuration code is:

```
var GetNaryadSalaryWork = builder.EntityType<SALARY_NARYAD_WORK>().Collection.Function("GetNaryadSalaryWork");
GetNaryadSalaryWork.Parameter<int>("pNaryadID");
GetNaryadSalaryWork.ReturnsCollectionFromEntitySet<SALARY_NARYAD_WORK>("SalaryNaryadWork");
GetNaryadSalaryWorkList.Namespace = "TechOrder.Functions";
```

But when I call this function by link `../SalaryNaryadWork/TechOrder.Functions.GetNaryadSalaryWork(pNaryadID=1)` I get only my entity without related entity:

[image]

Despite the fact that function returns related entity either (I saw that in variable `tmp` when debug function in visual studio)

So my question, is it possible to fix that and get related entity exactly by function without using expand option on `Get()` controller function?

Comment: I think you have to define `SALARY_WORK_LIST` as a ComplexType as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640296/how-to-access-a-child-object-using-odata-webapi-and-a-dto). Otherwise you have to use `expand`.